# Can you use sanitizer for Tayammum

Tags: tayammum

Salaam
If your access to water is limited and if earth is covered with snow, can you use sanitizer for Tayammum?
Shokra

Comment: If there is snow on the earth then you collect some snow in a pot, light a fire (or use any other energy source like an electric stove), put the pot on the fire, wait for the snow to melt to get water - and then do wudu with that water. Tayammum is only permitted when you do not have a way to get water. And further Tayammum can only be done with what is considered earth, such as sand or rock etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the most essential condition for performing tayammum is the absence of water (after searching for it intensively)  or a health condition that doesn't allow using water on your skin, meaning the use of water would cause severe harm or even your death.

Neither of both are applicable in the described case.

Secondly since most sanitizers use alcohol which is najis per default in Islam it is not permissible to use it on your skin for whatever application you'd think of especially in relation to a worship. It is rather essential to remove/clean the alcohol by washing it off from your skin.

Thirdly tayammum is performed by anything that is related to anything that comes from earth like soil, stones etc. See also [islamqa fatwa #36774](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/36774/tayammum-using-vessels-of-clay-or-walls).